# Range Selection and / or Using InputBox in Excel's VSTO AddIn on C# Leading To Error and Build Failed

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, vsto

It's quite strange to state hereby, but remains to be a fact that, in one of my VSTO projects while the following piece of simple code works well enough, in another project, while it's almost exactly the same, i.e. assigned to a Ribbon's Button, the latter project only reflects the message in Visual Studio's Footer as Build Failed, as per the image following the same i.e. without even an error being highlighted?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range RG = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.InputBox("Select your desired cells:", Type: 8);
        MessageBox.Show(RG.Address);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range RG2 = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection;
        MessageBox.Show(RG2.Address);
    }
```

[image]

What could be the reason???

The only difference between the said two projects is that in the latter project I am trying to use the WPF Forms in the same as per a video on YouTube, i.e.: [Office Addin with WPF Windows Controls for Word Excel Access Forms](https://youtu.be/mwRnY3LXsxQ)

Upon Googling led me to find out the solution of using the following line for matter of **Selection** but have been unable to find a similar solution for **Application.InputBox**:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range RG2 = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.RangeSelection
```

Even placing a [similar question on Microsoft's Answers Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-vsto-c-addins-range-selection-and-or-using/6595509e-d879-4657-abe9-2958af922856) led to no reply till now, :,-(

Any advice / help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i need more explanation about the issue like when you build the project is Excel Application was opened or its instance running in background(u can check it using task manager).
As  per my understanding, when you use below code
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range RG2 = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection; 
the Application.Selection is returning Object instance. And it is not mandatory to be Excel.Range .
for that you need to typecast and do null checking, otherwise it throw error at runtime.

Comment: To resolve your issue ,you can do one more thing , berfore building your solution/project , first clean the solution/project  and then build it .

Or Goto folder directory and delete bin and obj folder from all project folders and later build solution/project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite strange, but true enough. Till now the Visual Studio was not reflecting **any** error but today when I tried again to implement WPF in a VSTO it finally reflected that there was a **Casting Error**???

The said error also appeared for only few seconds and then again disappeared with the same  old footer reflecting build failed.

When I googled it no doubt turn out to be so and [the very first site clarifying the said matter](https://vbaoverall.com/name-manager-excel-vba-vsto-dot-net/) was quite fruitful enough.

Thus, changing my code to the following did turn out to be resulting to a **successful build**:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range RG = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.InputBox("Select your desired cells:", Type: 8);
    MessageBox.Show(RG.Address);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range RG2 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection;
    MessageBox.Show(RG2.Address);
}
```

Alhamdulillah!